# Invalid dataset name

Tags: vb.net

I made a dataset using bindingsouece and wizard.
Later I deleted it from my form, from the list below.
When I needed to make dataset with same name, it gave error that
dataset name is invalid as it already exists.
Why is this and where do I need to delete it to be able to use the same name again?
Thanks
Furqan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dataset would have been created and added to the project by the wizard - look for a file by the name of the dataset with a `.vb` suffix. You can delete it with all associated files.